# How to filter multiple files in Java by their names?

Tags: java, database, image

I have a directory with many image files in it. I am trying to write a simple code in Java which will be working with a database. Database will hold these image's filenames and some other data about them.

Most basic scenario: I want to run a query in the db then filter these images. For example, think about a query like 'SELECT filename FROM IMAGES WHERE filename like '%tree%''. This will give me a result array of "bigtree.jpg", "greentree.jpg", "oldtree.png" etc.. I want my simple program to list and show me only these files, I will pass that result_array to a method as a parameter, then it will load only these image files from the directory and display them.

The most basic approach, getting all files via "directory.**listFiles**()" and then checking every single file if it's filename is in the result_array is a horrible solution. If I wanted to filter something like only by extension (for example only .png files) I think **FileNameFilter** could be used but I want to use multiple filenames as the filter.

What kind of approach should I prefer?

Comment: You already have the file name. Just concat the file names on the result_array with base directory and open it. Probably I am missing something. If you know the base directory and the file name, why do you need to apply a filter? unless you need to search the file on the disk.

Comment: @printfmyname I need a array of File objects, do you say i should create this array by 'File temp = new File("path_of_filtered_file");' and adding this temp file to an array. I think this should do the trick, really, no need to refilter files again. Thanks for the idea.